# Java library for Bluetooth LE 4.0 for MsWindows and/or Mac OSX

Tags: java, bluetooth-lowenergy

http://bluecove.org/

BlueCove is a Java library for Bluetooth, for MsWindows, Mac OSX and others.

but it seems that it does not support Bluetooth Low Enegry 4.0.

Android has a standard Java library for Bluetooth LE 4.0:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html

Is there a Java library for Bluetooth LE 4.0 for MsWindows and/or Mac OSX?

Comment: Maybe: [SmartGattLib](https://github.com/movisens/SmartGattLib)

Comment: BGAPI for Java https://github.com/SINTEF-9012/bglib

Comment: Joe, BGLIB/BGAPI is specific to Bluegiga bluetooth. I am looking for a standard BLE4 library for MsWindows and/or MacOSX, such as the one for Android: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html

Comment: @David Portabella did you able to find any solution for the same..

Comment: No, I gave up at the time.

Answer (score 5):

After a long search without success on the same subject for myself, I'm pretty sure that there at present no library providing support Bluetooth LE on J2SE ...

JSR82 is for bluetooth 2.x only, and Bluetooth 4.x (Bluetooth LE) is a very different protocol.

So, this may be a good idea to start a new project on the subject, based for example on the [bluez](http://www.bluez.org/) stack on linux (or equivalent for MacOS X and Windows) or doing something like BGAPI (which apparently implements the bluetooth networking protocol, with links to a specific device)

Answer (score 4):

Intel's Edison project has a small wrapper API (read JNI) for BlueZ libs under Yocto Linux that gives full BLE support. You can find the source code in Github; [intel-iot-devkit/tinyb](https://github.com/intel-iot-devkit/tinyb/)

**UPDATE 2021:** There is now the possibility with Project Panama that native Bluetooth can be supported in Java. You would need to know a little about the platform and the library to use it. See Project Panama for more information; [projects/panama](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/panama/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12185774)

Comment: @ShreeKrishna, actually, it **is** the answer.

Comment: Happy to discover tinyb : at least, a solution exists now. So my (old) answer is no more relevant, and you should try this Intel project.

Comment: I am happy to have helped somebody out. Sometimes Java's lack of ability to touch hardware drives me nuts. There are other aspects to the Intel Edison projects like I2C sensors (accelerometers, gyroscopes, temperature) called mraa and a layer on top called upm. Together with BLE you have real potential all using Java. Things like robotics is not only practical but fun and easy.

Comment: The readme for tinyb says that it "requires GLib/GIO 2.40+".  That sounds like a linux library.  Has anyone made this solution work on Windows?  Thanks!

Comment: where is the bluetooth part of panama page? i found nothing over there... @JohnBryant .

Comment: Project Panama is the Java project that allows machine level memory access. It does not cover specific native libs like Bluetooth. You would need to know the native library to access it in this manner. Your particular Bluetooth library will have this documentation. If you don't want to work at the bare metal level you could always look at the Java JNA project. They have plenty of examples.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with Intel-IoT or Eclipse Kura projects? 
I am trying to work over them, but it seems they relay over bluez, and that means only linux and macos...

Implementing it via basic javascript under the browser could be a solution, but is still experimental into browsers and needs https, which is a problem under java desktop applications.

It can't be that no one has achieve this before and it's the first time I see this under java.

Any more help on this topic would be great!

Comment: That sounds interesting. Have you thought about opening a question?

Comment: No need ;) You can find a boilerplate about it on https://github.com/WebBluetoothCG/demos/tree/gh-pages/heart-rate-sensor

Comment: I have created an updated react version. It's dead easy. https://github.com/albertoSoto/react-ble-gatt

Comment: Although this doesn't answer the questions, I'm voting you up!

Answer (score 0):

This could probably be achieved by creating JNI ( java native interface ) wrappers around c++ libraries on windows. Project Panama is more recent and I guess it was created to replace all the hardwork of working with JNI, but I'm still mentioning this because I found a [repo](https://github.com/hdonk/javelin) that has written some JNI wrappers to access ble on windows. I haven't tested it myself and I'm not sure what functionalities it provides, but it should definitely help.

Comment: First of all, the question (that you answered) should have been closed (for the same reason that your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78173872/using-bluetooth-low-energy-ble-on-windows-with-java) was closed, namely that it is seeking recommendations for resources). Hence, strictly speaking, you should not answer such questions - even though this question was up-voted twenty times and also answered by others.